# Filtering empty strings from lists vs arrays

Tags: python, string, numpy

I have a list with empty strings:

```
test = ['foo', '', 'bar', '', 'baz']
```

The following code will strip the empty strings and return the desired output:

```
list(filter(None, test))
Out:['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

When I turn the list into a numpy array, applying the same function by mapping does not work:

```
test = np.array(['foo', '', 'bar', '', 'baz'], dtype='<U15')

def g(x):
    return list(filter(None, x))

def array_map(x):
    return np.array(list(map(g, x)))

array_map(test)
Out: array([list(['f', 'o', 'o']), list([]), list(['b', 'a', 'r']), list([]),
       list(['b', 'a', 'z'])], dtype=object)
```

Why does this happen and what is the correct, simple method to remove empty strings from a numpy array?

Comment: `test[test != ""]`?

Comment: I think numpy arrays hasn't a next method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I turn the list into a numpy array, applying the same function by mapping does not work

Right; the function *already turns your source sequence into the list that you want to make an array out of*, so there is no reason to do any mapping.

> Why does this happen

Mapping `g` onto `test` means that `g` is separately called with *each element of* `x`. The elements of `test` are strings; when `list(filter(None, x))` is evaluated with `x` being one of the strings from `test`, `filter` iterates over *the characters of* the string. All of those characters pass the filter, so a `list` is made that contains them. The `map`ped version of `test`, therefore, contains a bunch of lists of characters, which then is passed to `np.array`.

> and what is the correct, simple method to remove empty strings from a numpy array?

Well, if you wanted to do it with `filter`, it would look like passing the Numpy array to a *single* call to `filter`, and then constructing a new array from the result. Only, the resulting `filter` object won't be iterated over automatically by `np.array`, so you'd have to create e.g. a list first. Thus:

```
>>> np.array(list(filter(None, test)), dtype='<U15')
array(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], dtype='<U15')
```

(Notice that the `dtype` needs to be specified explicitly if you want it preserved; otherwise Numpy will infer the smallest type that suffices for the data.)

**However, it is better to use Numpy tools for this task.** The idiomatic way to remove data from an array is to create a mask that matches the elements you want, and index with that:

```
>>> test[test != '']
array(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], dtype='<U15')
```

(If you want to remove everything that's false-ish - i.e. that would fail to satisfy an `if` condition - you can use the somewhat awkwardly named `nonzero` method: `test[test.nonzero()]`.)

Answer (score 0):

```
In [714]: test = ['foo', '', 'bar', '', 'baz']
```

I like the expressiveness of list comprehensions:

```
In [715]: [s for s in test if s]                                                                     
Out[715]: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

This comprehension also works with an array - though it will be slower:

```
In [716]: aTest=np.array(test)                                                                       
In [717]: aTest                                                                                      
Out[717]: array(['foo', '', 'bar', '', 'baz'], dtype='<U3')
In [718]: np.array([s for s in aTest if s])                                                          
Out[718]: array(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], dtype='<U3')
```

An element of the array tests the same an element of a list.

`filter` acts the same way:

```
In [724]: list(filter(None, test))                                                                   
Out[724]: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
In [725]: list(filter(None, aTest))                                                                  
Out[725]: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

Your two function approach ends up applying `list` to each string, splitting it.  The outer `map` passes a string to `g`, not the whole list:

```
In [728]: def g(x): 
     ...:     return list(filter(None,x))                                                                                      
In [729]: list(map(g,test))                                                                          
Out[729]: [['f', 'o', 'o'], [], ['b', 'a', 'r'], [], ['b', 'a', 'z']]
In [732]: [list(s) for s in test]                                                                    
Out[732]: [['f', 'o', 'o'], [], ['b', 'a', 'r'], [], ['b', 'a', 'z']]
In [734]: list(g(test[0]))                                                                           
Out[734]: ['f', 'o', 'o']
```

As pointed out in the other answer, you can do the array filtering without a python level iteration:

```
In [736]: aTest==''                                                                                  
Out[736]: array([False,  True, False,  True, False])
In [737]: aTest[aTest!='']                                                                           
Out[737]: array(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], dtype='<U3')
```

For this small sample the list comprehension is fastest.  I expect though that with a 1000 string list/array, the array approach will scale better.

```
In [740]: timeit [s for s in test if s]                                                              
398 ns ± 10.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
In [741]: timeit aTest[aTest!='']                                                                    
3.99 µs ± 158 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [743]: timeit list(filter(None, test))                                                            
503 ns ± 9.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```